# Unable to list Requiredfields on VF Page

Tags: describesobject

I am trying to render the list of required fields for an sObject selected, here is how the page looks

[image: Get Required fields for selected object]

code for the page:

```
<apex:page controller="ObjectFieldExplorerController">
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:selectList value="{!selectedObject}" size="1">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!objectOptions}" />
            <apex:actionSupport reRender="form" event="onchange" />
        </apex:selectList>
        <apex:selectList value="{!selectedField}" size="1">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!fieldOptions}" />
        </apex:selectList>
                <apex:pageBlock>
                <apex:pageblocktable value="{!getRequiredFields}" var="results">
</apex:pageblocktable>
</apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex code:

```
public class ObjectFieldExplorerController {

    public String selectedObject { get; set; }
    public String selectedField { get; set; }
      public List<String> requiredfields=new List<String>();


    public SelectOption[] getObjectOptions() {
        SelectOption[] results = new SelectOption[] { new SelectOption('','-- none --') };
        for(SObjectType sType: Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values()) {
            DescribeSObjectResult res = sType.getDescribe();

            results.add(new SelectOption(res.getName(), res.getLabel()));
            results.sort();
        }
        return results;    
    }

    public SelectOption[] getFieldOptions() {
        SelectOption[] results = new SelectOption[] { new SelectOption('','-- none --') };
        if(selectedObject != null) {
            for(SObjectField sField: Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(selectedObject).getDescribe().fields.getMap().values()) {
                DescribeFieldResult res = sField.getDescribe();
                results.add(new SelectOption(res.getName(), res.getLabel()));
                results.sort();
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    public void getRequiredFields(){
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = Account.sObjectType.getDescribe();
    Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> M = r.fields.getMap();
    for(String fieldName : M.keySet()) { 
    Schema.SObjectField field = M.get(fieldName);
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = field.getDescribe();
    //A nillable field can have empty content. A isNillable Boolean non-nillable
    // field must have a value for the object to be
    // created or saved. 
    // if F.isNillable() is false then field is mandatory
    if( F.isCreateable()  && !F.isNillable() && !F.isDefaultedOnCreate())
 {
//This is mandatory / required field

      requiredfields.add(fieldName);

 }
 system.debug('==>requiredfields==>'+requiredfields);
}
return requiredfields;

    }
}
```

Comment: did your apex class compiled. I dont think void method will return any value.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to specify why the observed behavior differs from what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if your code even compiled and got the preview of the visualforce as you are showing in your screenshot.

I tried your code in my org and made few changes and here is the working code:

**vf page**:

```
<apex:page controller="ObjectFieldExplorerController">
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:selectList value="{!selectedObject}" size="1">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!objectOptions}" />
            <apex:actionSupport reRender="form" event="onchange" />
        </apex:selectList>
        <apex:selectList value="{!selectedField}" size="1">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!fieldOptions}" />
        </apex:selectList>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageblocktable value="{!requiredfields}" var="results">
                <apex:column value="{!results}"></apex:column>
            </apex:pageblocktable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class ObjectFieldExplorerController {

    public String selectedObject { get; set; }
    public String selectedField { get; set; }
    public List<String> requiredfields=new List<String>();


    public SelectOption[] getObjectOptions() {
        SelectOption[] results = new SelectOption[] { new SelectOption('','-- none --') };
        for(SObjectType sType: Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values()) {
            DescribeSObjectResult res = sType.getDescribe();

            results.add(new SelectOption(res.getName(), res.getLabel()));
            results.sort();
        }
        return results;    
    }

    public SelectOption[] getFieldOptions() {
        SelectOption[] results = new SelectOption[] { new SelectOption('','-- none --') };
        if(selectedObject != null) {
            for(SObjectField sField: Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(selectedObject).getDescribe().fields.getMap().values()) {
                DescribeFieldResult res = sField.getDescribe();
                results.add(new SelectOption(res.getName(), res.getLabel()));
                results.sort();
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    public List<String> getRequiredFields(){

        if(selectedObject != NULL){
            requiredfields = new List<String>();
            Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(selectedObject).getDescribe();
            Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> M = r.fields.getMap();
            for(String fieldName : M.keySet()) { 
                Schema.SObjectField field = M.get(fieldName);
                Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = field.getDescribe();
                //A nillable field can have empty content. A isNillable Boolean non-nillable
                // field must have a value for the object to be
                // created or saved. 
                // if F.isNillable() is false then field is mandatory
                if( F.isCreateable()  && !F.isNillable() && !F.isDefaultedOnCreate()){
                    //This is mandatory / required field
                  requiredfields.add(fieldName);
                }   
                system.debug('==>requiredfields==>'+requiredfields);
            }
            return requiredfields;          
        }
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Changes made to your code:

1. Your method `getRequiredFields` signature was void but it should be `List<String>`
2. In `getRequiredFields` method, Account object is hard coded instead of trying to get the required fields for the object user selected on the UI. This is the corrected code:

   ```
   Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(selectedObject).getDescribe();
   ```
3. I also added a condition to check `selectedObject` variable is not NULL before trying to get required fields for the object.

Please comment if you need further explanation on this.

Comment: Thank you javanoob for the correction, I should have noticed some of these.